# Verification of JK Flip Flop shows incorrect results

Tags: verilog, fpga

I designed a JK Flip Flop.   Now I want to automate the verification.  For that, I recorded input output combinations in an array and verified it using a `for` loop.  But, some of my verification gives incorrect result.

I had already done the manual verification of the design, and I get the required out.

Here is my design

```
    module jkff(clk,j,k,q);
    
    input clk,j,k;
    output  q;
    reg q;
    
    always @ (posedge clk)  
        case ({j,k})  
            2'b00 :  q <= q;  
            2'b01 :  q <= 0;  
            2'b10 :  q <= 1;  
            2'b11 :  q <= ~q;  
        endcase  
        endmodule
```

Here is my TestBench

```
    module tb_jk;  
        reg j;  
        reg k;  
        reg clk; 
        wire q;
        reg j_array[1:8];
        reg k_array[1:8];
        reg q_array[1:8];
        integer i;
    
        initial begin  
            j_array[1] =1'b0;
            j_array[2] =1'b0;
            j_array[3] =1'b0;
            j_array[4] =1'b1;
            j_array[5] =1'b1;
            j_array[6] =1'b1;
            j_array[7] =1'b1;
            j_array[8] =1'b1;
    
            k_array[1] =1'b0;
            k_array[2] =1'b1;
            k_array[3] =1'b1;
            k_array[4] =1'b0;
            k_array[5] =1'b0;
            k_array[6] =1'b1;
            k_array[7] =1'b1;
            k_array[8] =1'b1;
    
            q_array[1] =1'bx;
            q_array[2] =1'bx;
            q_array[3] =1'b0;
            q_array[4] =1'b0;
            q_array[5] =1'b1;
            q_array[6] =1'b1;
            q_array[7] =1'b0;
            q_array[8] =1'b1;
        end
    
        jkff    jk0 ( .j(j),  
            .k(k),  
            .clk(clk),  
            .q(q));  
    
        initial begin  
            clk = 1'b0;
            j = 1'b0;
            k = 1'b0;
        end
        initial begin
            main;
        end
        task main; 
            fork
                clock_gen;
                operation_flow;
                debug_output;
                endsimulation;
            join
        endtask
        task clock_gen;
            forever #5 clk = ~clk;  
        endtask
        task operation_flow;
            begin
                for(i =1;i<=8;i= i+1)
                begin
                    j<=j_array[i];
                    k<=k_array[i];
                    #(10);
                    if(q == q_array[i]) begin
                        $display("Correct!..");
                        $display("q_array[%d] = %d",i,q_array[i]);
                        $display("j = %d k= %d q =%d",j,k,q);
                    end
                    else begin
                        $display("Wrong!...");
                        $display("q_array[%d] = %d",i,q_array[i]);
                        $display("j = %d k= %d q =%d",j,k,q);
    
                    end
                end
                    $display("Verification Finished!..");
            end
        endtask
        task debug_output;
            begin
                $dumpfile("jk_ff.vcd");
                $dumpvars;
            end
        endtask
        task endsimulation;
            begin
                #200
                $display("-------------- THE SIMUALTION END ------------");
                $finish;
            end
        endtask
        endmodule
```

Logs

```
    VCD info: dumpfile jk_ff.vcd opened for output.
    Wrong!...
    q_array[          1] = x
    j = 0 k= 0 q =x
    Wrong!...
    q_array[          2] = x
    j = 0 k= 1 q =0
    Correct!..
    q_array[          3] = 0
    j = 0 k= 1 q =0
    Wrong!...
    q_array[          4] = 0
    j = 1 k= 0 q =1
    Correct!..
    q_array[          5] = 1
    j = 1 k= 0 q =1
    Wrong!...
    q_array[          6] = 1
    j = 1 k= 1 q =0
    Wrong!...
    q_array[          7] = 0
    j = 1 k= 1 q =1
    Wrong!...
    q_array[          8] = 1
    j = 1 k= 1 q =0
    Verification Finished!..
    -------------- THE SIMUALTION END ------------
```

I am not able to find what is the problem in automation in verifying the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

When you compare against unknown values (`x`), you must use the case equality operator (`===`).

You are also sampling your output data at the wrong time.  One way to fix this is to sample on the opposite edge of the clock from how your output is driven.

Refer to the `////` comments to see which lines I changed:

```
task operation_flow;
    begin
        for(i =1;i<=8;i= i+1)
        begin
            j<=j_array[i];
            k<=k_array[i];
            @(negedge clk); ////
            if(q === q_array[i]) begin ////
                $display($time, " Correct!..");
                $display("q_array[%d] = %d",i,q_array[i]);
                $display("j = %d k= %d q =%d",j,k,q);
            end
            else begin
                $display($time, " Wrong!...");
                $display("q_array[%d] = %d",i,q_array[i]);
                $display("j = %d k= %d q =%d",j,k,q);

            end
            @(posedge clk); ////
        end
            $display("Verification Finished!..");
    end
endtask
```

I also added `$time` to the `$display` statement to give you more debugging information in your log file.

When I run the simulation now, I do not see `Wrong!` messages.